# conditional goto is not working in soap ui

Tags: soapui

I have created soap ui rest service test case with 4 steps.

1. Addconsumer request.
2. conditiongoto - if customer is premiere target step4
3. addpointrequest
4. gainpointrequest

When the second step gets true, i am being navigated to step 4.
but if it is false it is running step 3 and step 4.

How to restrict this? I need to execute step 3 only. step 4 is for premier consumer...

Regards,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to step 3 means passing control flow to this step and all subsequent ones. You need to explicitly jump over your step 4 after jumping to step 3. For these purposes two Groovy steps can be created: (1)empty final step after the last conditional branch and (2) Groovy step with *testRunner.gotoStepByName* call that jumps to that final step after your addpointrequest is complete.

Here are modified test steps:

1. Addconsumer request.
2. conditiongoto - if customer is premiere target step4
3. addpointrequest
4. Groovy Script: testRunner.gotoStepByName("conditiongoto_end")
5. gainpointrequest
6. conditiongoto_end (empty Groovy Script step)

For more references please see [Controlling flow tutorial](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/controlling-flow.html)